# YEAR() fitting to WEEKNUM(...,21) in Excel

Tags: excel, week-number

I'm looking for a way to specify return 2015 for a date within this week, but in Calendar Year 2014.
This current week according to the Thursday system is Week 01/2015. But the Year function will still return 2014.

Something like:
IF(AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21)=52,WEEKNUM(TODAY()+7,21)<>53),YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())

but a little bit more reliable and elegant.

Anybody got something?

Happy Happy

Ben-san

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Year" of the week is determined by the year of the `Thursday` of that week (assuming ISO week numbers) so you can just find the Thursday and then get the year of that date, i.e. for any date in A1

`=YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1,3)+3)`

or, similarly, for today's date

`=YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)+3)`

This works for any date in any year.......and might put days in Jan in the previous year also, e.g. 3rd Jan 2016 is in the last week of 2015

Comment: marvelous. Thanks a mil.